# Wait-Task outputs an error when deploying VMs from a .csv file

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I wrote a GUI script that clones VMs from a template and gives them a static IP address that they get from a .csv file.

Everything seems to work fine except for an error I'm getting. The clone completes successfully anyway, but I'm not sure how to fix the error or if I even should.

```bsh
function StartClone {
    $VM_List = Import-Csv $csvTB.Text
    $numClones = [int]((Get-Content $csvTB.Text).Length)
    $vmh = Get-VMHost
    $NewParameters = @{
        # Name                = ''
        Template            = $TemplateMenu.Text
        Datastore           = $DatastoreMenu.Text
        DiskStorageFormat   = 'Thin'
        Location            = $FolderCB.Text
        OSCustomizationSpec = $CustomizationCB.Text
        VMHost              = Get-Random -InputObject $vmh
        Server              = $VCenterTB.Text
        RunAsync            = $true
    }

    $SetParameters = @{
        NumCpu              = $CPU_TB.Text
        MemoryGB            = $RAM_TB.Text
        Notes               = $NotesTB.Text
        Confirm             = $false
    }

    $taskList = if ($NumClones -gt 0) {
        # foreach ($item in (Import-Csv $csvTB.Text))
        $VM_List | ForEach-Object {
            $NewParameters['Name'] = "$($_.Hostname)"
            Get-OSCustomizationSpec -name $CustomizationCB.Text | Get-OSCustomizationNICMapping | Set-OSCustomizationNICMapping -IPMode UseStaticIP -IPAddress "$($_.IP)" -SubNetMask "$($_.Subnet)" -DefaultGateway "$($_.Gateway)" -Dns ""
            New-VM @NewParameters
        }
    }

    $newVM = $taskList | Wait-Task -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $newVM | Set-VM @SetParameters
    $newVM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $VLAN_CB.Text -Confirm:$false
    if ($StartVM_CB.Checked -eq $true) {$newVM | Start-VM }
 }
```

The error I get is related to the `Wait-Task` command which I have to use to wait for the VMs to actually be done cloning.

```
Wait-Task : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because 
the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of 
the parameters that take pipeline input.

At line:465 char:26
+     $newVM = $taskList | Wait-Task
+                          ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (UseStaticIP:192.168.1.1:PSObject) [Wait-Tas     k], ParameterBindingException                                                                     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,VMware.VimAutomation.Common.Commands.Cmdlets.     WaitTask
```

The error repeats for each VM in my .csv file, so if I have 4 VMs that I want to deploy, it will pop up 4 times. As the error suggests, it's related to the fact I'm looping over the .csv file and creating a new VM with with iteration, but like I said, everything completes without issues and the VMs are working.

Any input on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`New-VM` returns a `VirtualMachineImpl` object, and `Wait-Task` has nothing to do it...

If you add the `-RunAsync` parameter to `New-VM` it will return a `TaskImpl` object, then you can pipe the results to the `Wait-Task` cmdlet.